# How to solo-hunt demons as a Level 220+ Royal Paladin and make a profit?

Tags: tibia

In [Tibia](http://www.tibia.com/), is it possible to solo-hunt demons as a Level 220+ Royal Paladin while still making a profit from the hunt?

I remember trying this in Goroma, but there is such a huge spawn of demons there that I ended up wasting a lot of time and resources just to kill a few of them.

What locations would you suggest to do this? Any special strategies?

P.S. Can someone add the Tibia tag please? Thanks.

Comment: @Sardathrion Nothing to do with *table-top* RPGs. But fair enough. I’ve flagged the post asking to move it to Gaming.

Comment: @MathiasBynens yes, we only do table top RPGs here.

Answer (score 5):

It's really simple. You can go to Yalahar respawn. I usually hunt on the east resppawn, but west is good too.

I take 800 SMP's and 2000 Crystalline arrows, and with those supplies i can kill 80 - 90 demon and get a pretty decent profit (100k+).

In this video you can learn how to hunt there (pt-br)